# Input file type hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide the browse button for users to upload a file. How do I do it?

```css
.fa-cloud-upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<label class="file_upload">
     <input type="file" name="uploads" accept="image/*, video/*"/><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 85px;"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: Your css is targeting the icon after the input, not the input itself, which you can hide with a display none.

Comment: How can I hide it?

Comment: Either inline a style="display:none" or give it css rule that does effectively the same thing.

Comment: Bare in mind that hiding the upload button does not prevent a file from being uploaded all the way.

Comment: You want to hide or disable it?

Comment: @Ryan I think my answer should help but if it doesn't let me know and theres other options we can try

Comment: I mean I wanted to hiide it with an Icon

Comment: @Ryan Can you explain further please

Comment: @Ryan do you mean when the user clicks the icon you want to toggle the visibility of the file input?

Answer (score 6):

You can just hide the input and use label to open the file see the example bellow:

```html
<label for="myInputFile">
  <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/699329-icon-57-document-download-128.png">
  <input type="file" name="myInputFile" id="myInputFile" style="display:none;" />
</label>
```

Comment: better than triggering the file input via javascript

Comment: i think its cleaner and easier to understand

Comment: Yes Cleaner it is

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide the input and trigger it when user clicks the icon:

```html
Click the image to select file
<br>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-9/256/open-file-icon.png" width="50" height="50" onclick="document.getElementById('mycustomid').click();" style="cursor: pointer;">
<input type="file" id="mycustomid" style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpy add `display: none;` to hide the input element.

```
input {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just hide your file input field.

```css
label input[ type="file" ] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="file" />
  <span>Icon</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Your Font-Awesome icon should appears where you try it in your environnement. :

```css
    .file_upload {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .btn {
      border: 0px solid gray;
      color: blue;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 8px 20px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .file_upload input[type=file] {
      font-size: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      opacity: 0;

    }
```

```html
<div class="file_upload">
  <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 15px;">X</i></button>
  <input type="file" name="uploads" accept="image/*, video/*"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide the `input` with `display:none`

```css
.fa-cloud-upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
}
.file_upload input[type="file"]{display:none}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<label class="file_upload">
  <input type="file" name="uploads" accept="image/*, video/*"/>
  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.fa-cloud-upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<label class="file_upload">
     <input type="file" name="uploads" accept="image/*, video/*"/><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 85px;"></i>
</label>
```